# jQuery slider not adding active slide class

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm having an issue with a slider I've put together (with navigation to each slide). The issue being that the `.active-slide` class is not being added correctly to the next slide. I've had this working in CodePen - http://codepen.io/davelivesey/pen/mEBkAa - but as soon as I transplant that into my project it breaks, the main issue being the `.active-slide` class is no longer added to the next slide.

I've added a `$(document).ready( ...` around it, but this doesn't fix it. There are no conflicts with any other code I've written and both the CodePen and the project use the same version of jQuery (2.2.4).

Here's the code that's not working in the project. I've removed some of the CSS for the sake of brevity!

HTML

```
<div id="slider">
  <div class="slide">I'm slide one.</div>
  <div class="slide">I'm slide two.</div>
  <div class="slide">I'm slide three.</div>
</div>
```

CSS(SASS)

```
#slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgb(240,240,240);

  .slide {
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    display: none;
  }
}

.slide.active-slide {
  display: block;
}

#slider-nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;

    li {
      display: inline-block;
      margin-right: 5px;

      a span {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 10px; height: 10px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        border: 1px solid rgb(130,130,130);
    }
  }

  li.active a span {
    background-color: rgb(180,180,180);
  }
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    var $slides  = $('#slider .slide'),
        $navWrap = $('#slider-nav ul');

    function nextSlide() {
        var $next = $('#slider-nav ul li.active').next();
        if ($next.length === 0){
            $next = $('#slider-nav ul li:first-of-type');
        }
        $next.click();
    }
    function slideTransition(index) {

        $('#slider .slide.active-slide').delay(6000).fadeOut(500, function() {
            $(this).removeClass('active-slide');
        });

        $('#slider .slide:eq(' + index + ')').fadeIn(500, function() {
            $(this).addClass('active-slide');
        });
    }

    $slides.each( function(index) {
        $navWrap.append('<li><a href="#link'+index+'"><span></span></a></li>');
    });

    var timer = setInterval(nextSlide, 6000);
    $('#slider .slide:first').addClass('active-slide').fadeIn(200);
    $('#slider-nav ul li').click(function() {
        clearInterval(timer);
        $(this).siblings('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        var index = $(this).index('li');
        slideTransition(index);
        timer = setInterval(nextSlide, 6000);
        return false;
    });

    $('#slider-nav ul li:first-of-type').click();

});
```

Comment: I've noticed a missing closing "}" in your SASS...

Comment: Good spot - fixed :)

Comment: Is the slider still not working? @DPL1984

Comment: Unfortunately not - I've narrowed down the issue to the `slideTransition` function however.